# PyInstaller packages math kernel libraries dlls which are not necessary

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to create a stand alone executable from a python files. I notice that many math kernel libraries are also bundles. The following are the list of dlls, and thus increases the size of my package.  This was seen on a windows 10 machine.

`mkl_avx.dll
    mkl_avx2.dll
    mkl_avx512.dll
    mkl_avx512_mic.dll
    mkl_core.dll
    mkl_thread.dll
    mkl_mic.dll
    mkl_mic3.dll
    mkl_pgi_thread.dll
    mkl_rt.dll
    mkl_scalapack_ilp64.dll
    mkl_sequential.dll
    mkl_vml_avx.dll
    mkl_vml_avx512.dll
    mkl_vml_cmpt.dll
    mkl_vml_mc.dll
    mkl_vml_mc3.dll`

I tried on a different windows 10 machine i did not see these dlls being packaged but the executable runs in both the machines. I just wanted to understand why are these dlls packaged?
 Is there a way i can exclude them?

Are these included as part of any python package? My pip list is as follows

```
altgraph (0.15)
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
backports.functools-lru-cache (1.5)
certifi (2018.1.18)
cffi (1.11.4)
chardet (3.0.4)
conda (4.4.10)
cryptography (2.1.4)
cycler (0.10.0)
future (0.16.0)
idna (2.6)
kiwisolver (1.0.1)
macholib (1.8)
matplotlib (2.2.0)
menuinst (1.4.11)
numpy (1.14.1)
pandas (0.22.0)
pefile (2017.11.5)
pip (9.0.1)
pycosat (0.6.3)
pycparser (2.18)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
PyInstaller (3.3.1)
pyOpenSSL (17.5.0)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
PySocks (1.6.7)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2018.3)
pywin32 (222)
requests (2.18.4)
ruamel-yaml (0.15.35)
setuptools (38.4.0)
six (1.11.0)
tornado (4.5.3)
urllib3 (1.22)
wheel (0.30.0)
win-inet-pton (1.0.1)
wincertstore (0.2)
XlsxWriter (1.0.2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after doing few experiments. I was using python with anaconda, and when i install numpy from this python it installed packages like `mkl` along with numpy installation. Hence these were getting packaged along with numpy when i run pyinstaller. 
  Solution was i had to anaconda and installed miniconda3, then installed relevent packages and used pyinstaller. this time mkl package was not installed. and hence problem solved.

Comment: Alternatively, on Anaconda, install the `nomkl` package in the dedicated environment. The size difference will be significant! https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nomkl